# Trying to read text file data into an array of structs?

Tags: c, arrays, file, struct, text-files

Here is what I want to do:

- Read my 2 text files into an "array of structs" (this is how it is worded on my assignment).
- Dynamically create sufficient memory for each entry read from the file

Here is one of the structs I am working with:

```
typedef struct {
    int eventid;
    char eventdate[20];
    char venuename[20];
    char country[20];               
    int rockid;
} Venue;
```

Within my main function I have the array setup to receive the text as:

```
Venue *(places[20]);
```

Now comes the more complex part. I need to open the file for reading (I got this to work perfectly) and then dynamically allocate the memory for each entry. I know I need to use malloc to do this but I have never used it before and am sort of at a loss. Here is what I have so far:

```
void load_data(void)
{   
char buffer[20]; //stating that each line can't be longer than 20 chars 
int i = 0,len;   //declaring 2 int variables

FILE * venuePtr=fopen("venueinfo.txt", "r");
if (venuePtr != NULL)
    printf("\n**Venue info file has been opened!**\n");

else{ 
    printf("\nPlease create a file named venueinfo.txt and restart!\n");
    } //so far so good...

    while (!feof(venuePtr)){ //while we have not found the eof key...
    fscanf(venuePtr,"%s",buffer); //we scan each line of text
    len = strlen(buffer); //find the length (len) of the string  
    places[i]=(char*)malloc(len+1);  //allocate memory space for the word here
    strcpy(places[i],buffer); //copy a word into our array
    ++i; //finally we move on to the next element in the array 
} //end while
```

The problem resides in the while loop and I have been working this for 2 days straight. I have 5 members in my struct and am thinking that strcpy may not work. This is only part of the problem though I am sure. I just can't wrap my head around reading in everything. The file itself is a super simple txt file and looks like this:

```
1 Jan10 Citadel Belgium 8
4 May05 Sunrise Belize 6
3 Jun17 Footloose Brazil 4
```

Comment: It would help if you would say what you're expecting to have happen, as well as what is happening that you don't want.

Comment: The things you need to think about are: How is the data stored in your file? Is it in delimited fields? What is the format of the data? After you've established that, you'll need to consider using sscanf of strtok to parse the data, and copy into your struct fields.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to copy string into the venue structure, how do you expect that to work ?
    strcpy(venue[i],buffer);

please give an example of your file, you probably need to parse each element and write it to structure members

Comment: again you are doing the same thing, can you print buffer after reading and i am guessing you want to populate the structure right, for that you cannot just strcpy.... you need to parse this buffer string and obtain individual values of the structure and assign .... please try to rethink this, i won't be writing code here but if you try i can correct you

Answer (score 0):

**Stuff you can skip but should eventually do:**

use function(void), not just empty() for functions.  visual studio, which you are using allows it, but it's bad format.

declaring global variables is likewise bad form.  You want to declare them in main and pass them in.

finally, you want to return.  return 0 from a successful run of main.  If you have a void function, still, return; before the final closing '}' character of the function.

oh and fscan_s isn't portable, it's a Microsoft function.

**stuff you actually asked about:**

Now, onto your problem.  Don't allocate memory and assign it.  You have statically allocated memory for your structures, and for your strings, by making them arrays with a given number of characters.  If you want to statically allocate memory, you need to use a pointer.

if you scan the first number, the rock id into id, you would assign the first venue's rock id as,

venue[0].rockid = id;

for arrays, you do have to string copy.  You already allocated memory for them, so you just have to use strcpy.

but you can't just copy strings into the structure and have it all end up in the right place. You need to get each part and add it seperately

That means you either need to read in each element separately, like "%d%s" to read an int then a string, or whatever, or you need to split up your string after reading in the whole thing.  **NOTE** 
That %s won't read the whole line!!! It will stop at the first white-space character (new line, tab, even a space) so if you %s "hi there" you get "hi".  You may want to use %[^\n] which while characters don't match \n.

My suggestion is to use fscanf with multiple items, but if you need to split the string up, you want to use sscanf, which lets you scan a string again.

Finally, you don't need to test for feof, and that's actually problematic.  It's far better to use while (fscanf(parameters go in here) > 0) since EOF is generally -1 and 0 means no items were scanned.  Either way, you are done reading.

I suggest you start small.  It looks like you are trying to jump ahead without understanding fundamentals, and C is kinda brutal about needing to know those.

Good luck.

P.S. It's very possible I made a small mistake here just now, writing this, because I'm not a C expert, but I'm sure somebody will come along and help me.  Finding mistakes is how we learn, so don't get discouraged. :)

Comment: Cool.  If someone here helped you, you may want to upvote them or click the check mark to accept their answer as correct.  This helps future people with similar issues.  It's also good to include the old code before any edits, so that they can see the issues.